# How to multiply each digit by a number in a list in order

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that will multiply each digit with a number in the list in order

so lets say my inputted number is `1234`, then

- `1` will be multiplied by `4`
- `2` will be multiplied by `8`
- `3` will be multiplied by `5`, and so on

```py
frequentNum = input("please enter 4 digit frequent number: ")
arr = [4, 8, 5, 7]
for i in str(frequentNum):
  for j in arr:
    value = int(i) * j 
    print(value)
```

I tried this code but it multiplies each digit with every number in the list

I was trying to get an output of

```
4
16
15
28
```

Comment: `frequentNum` is already a string you don't need to call `str()`

Comment: You should iterate over the list and digits in parallel, not with nested loops. `for i, j in zip(frequentNum, arr):`

Comment: `for i, j in zip(arr, frequentNum): print(i * int(j))`